# Please suggest some tutorial for learning pointcut expression

Tags: java, aop, aspectj, pointcuts

Please suggest some tutorial/cheatsheet for learning pointcut expression.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [AspectJ programmers guide](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/progguide/index.html) has plenty examples, looks straightforward.

Answer (score 2):

[AspectJ in Action](http://www.manning.com/laddad2/) is also a great source of information on AOP and AspectJ.

Answer (score 0):

Spring.Net has excellent documentation which can be downloaded from here: http://www.springframework.net/documentation.html

It has a very good general introduction to AOP and examples and sample AOP programs to get you started. Not knowing much about AOP, but knowing a bit about Spring.Net, I found this enough to get an AOP-based logging system up and running.